# Jetpack Compose - MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack-compose, android-motionlayout

What is the equivalent of :

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="1500"
    motion:motionInterpolator="linear">
    <OnSwipe
        motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
        motion:touchAnchorId="@id/view1"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />
</Transition>
```

On MotionLayout for Compose ?
I do not see the answear on both of those links :

https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/Introduction-to-MotionLayout-in-Compose
https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/Compose-MotionLayout-JSON-Syntax

I would like to animate my scene only if I manually scroll, not by clicking on a button like in the examples.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

MotionLayout in Compose has no built in support of  (yet).

Compose has swipe handling
One approach looks like this:

```
var componentHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(1000f) }
val swipeableState = rememberSwipeableState("Bottom")
val anchors = mapOf(0f to "Bottom", componentHeight to "Top")
val mprogress = (swipeableState.offset.value / componentHeight)
```

progress is then passed into the MotionLayout Composable.

```
  MotionLayout(motionScene = "",  progress = mprogress, ...)
```

[Here](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/blob/f7519a97672d18fa8a5afcc0ff7fa60af68f2b46/projects/ComposeConstraintLayout/app/src/main/java/com/example/constraintlayout/MotionComposeExamples.kt#L875) is an examples how you would code it.

Comment: Great ! This is exactly what I need ! Thank you. Do you know if it is possible to add a SwipeRefresh on top of the MotionLayout ?

Comment: Other question : do you know how to make a verticalBias with that JSON syntax ? I do not find the paramater.

Comment: To sump up, is there a link where I can find all different json values ?

Comment: https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/wiki/ConstraintSet-JSON5-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Since `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.1.0-alpha01` you can now use `onSwipe` setting for transaction in `MotionScene`:

```
MotionScene {
    val anchorComposable = createRefFor("someId")
    val state1 = constraintSet {
        //some constraints
    }
    val state2 = constraintSet {
        //some constraints
    }

    transition(state1, state2, "default") {
        onSwipe = OnSwipe(
            anchor = anchorComposable,
            direction = SwipeDirection.Up,
            side = SwipeSide.Top,
        )
    }
}
```

Pass this scene to `MotionLayout` and you'll get the desired swipe effect. Unfortunately, they still don't have all the functionality of xml `MotionLayout`, i.e. there is no `TransitionListener`, so you can't check if swipe is started or completed. Another important drawback is that all clickable composables are excluded from swipable zone.